# Convert specific date & time based on user location to utc date & time

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I am working on a JavaScript based application. In my application, we have built a list from which user can select a time.

The list looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HOPp.png)

Once the user selects a time from the list, based on todays date, I need to convert the date (which is today's date) and the time picked by user into UTC time.

There are tons of post which talks about converting date time into UTC but each having its pros & cons. Some of the post are old and JavaScript is evolving everyday.

I need to take users location into consideration while converting the date. I will assume what ever location/timezone set on user machine as the right location / timezone.

Answer (score 0):

`var userTime = new Date();` should give you something like:
`Sun Dec 27 2015 21:58:08 GMT-0600 (CST)` when you call `userTime`.

You can either do some simple math there, or you could use
`userTime.toISOString();` and have the GMT time converted for you, e.g. 
`"2015-12-28T04:04:07.626Z"`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find location you can HTML5 geolocation otherwise new Date wll return the `Date` object

You can do it either by using `.toISOSTring()` or by using `.toUTCString().`

```
(function(){
 var a = new Date();
// Using .toISOSTring
document.getElementById('demo').textContent = a.toISOString();

var b =new Date(new Date().toUTCString().substr(0, 25))
document.getElementById('demo1').textContent = b
}())
```

[WORKING MODEL](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/tvkeypxk/)

**EDIT**

You can also come up with a function to return a result in UTC format

```
    function convertDateToUTC(date) { return new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), 
date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), 
date.getUTCSeconds()); 
    }
```

[WORKING MODEL 2](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/tvkeypxk/1/)